# What is the right amount of abstraction from the data-layer?

Tags: architecture, datamapper, separation-of-concerns

I'm currently devising my application's persistence framework...and I am debating two solutions for abstraction.

**Option 1.** The first, and simpler (but possibly more coupled to the database is a 2 layered approach. In this approach, data mappers pull data from the database and build business entities.

Rough diagram of workflow:

```
UserEntity <= UserMapper => Database
```

**Option 2.** The second, and more flexible (but possible overkill) approach is a 3 layered approach. In this approach, we have a THIRD object who's job it is to solely speak to the database, and return an array of data to the Data Mapper, who then creates an object.

Rough diagram:

```
UserEntity <= UserMapper <= UserDataRetriever => Database
```

Obviously the benefit of the first option is that it's simpler and therefore quicker to create. The benefit of the second option is that it's easier to change out my persistence methods, as I'd only have to change my DataRetriever's connection to the DB (and related queries).

As this site is going to grow in size very fast, I'd like to choose the most flexible option, without getting into anti-pattern land.

Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
Entity <=> Repository pattern <=> DataSource
```

The repository would do the mapping (or use an mapping layer internally).

The repository itself could use vanilla ADO.NET, and OR/M mapper, a webservice or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the response - in this case, the repo knows about to speak w/ the db? Is it a set of classes that are each built for an entity? I'll research more about it myself, as well...

Comment: It's a set of classes built for each root and it's aggregates. i.e. one for Order + OrderLines + OrderHistory etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the diagram for the **Option 2** would be a bit more involved:

```
UserEntity <= UserMapper <= UserDataEntity <= UserDataRetriever => Database
```

`UserMapper` would have to map from one type to another, hence `UserDataEntity`. It's conceptually awkward to map directly from `UserDataRetriever` to `UserEntity`. You might be implying the following diagram for the second option:

```
UserEntity <= UserMapper <= [list of arrays] <= UserDataRetriever => Database
```

Anyway, **Option 1** is different here in a way that `UserMapper` includes in itself a functionality of: `[list of arrays]/UserDataEntity <= UserDataRetriever`.

Neither of the options is inherently better. It depends on the number of entities and how easy it is to map between persistence and domain layers.

You may want to try **Option 1.5** instead: your basic approach is Option 1. At the same time you design `UserMapper` to have separate and well defined methods to a) retrieve data, and b) map data. This way you will start lean and have an easy way to refactor those methods into separate classes down the road if necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right about adding the UserDataRetriever - I didn't include that in the example, but definitely have been using one. And, yes, it does return a set of data arrays. I might do that 1.5 option that you offered though. I like the option to easily refactor :)